# Nextjs Image tag adds horizontal scrollbar tailwindcss

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

My web page should have three images equaly sized along the middle like so:
[image]

This works well, however, whenever I add an image, even if it is only one and it is outside all containers, it adds a vertical scrollbar and a small amount of white space to the right. Even if the image isnt near the right side.
I a using NextJS and Tailwindcss.
my code:

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-screen h-screen text-black bg-white max-w-screen">
      
      <Navbar />
      <hr className="border-t-black"></hr>

      <div className="flex justify-center text-center w-screen">
        <h1 className="text-2xl m-5 sm:text-4xl font-bold sm:m-6">At Emery's Honey we believe raw honey is best as it's not processed in any way on it's journey from the beehive to the jar.</h1>
      </div>

      <div className="sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:justify-items-center">
        <div className="aspect-[3/4]">
          <Image src={Bee} alt="Bee"  />
        </div>
        <div className="aspect-[3/4]">
          <Image src={Bees} alt="Bees" />
        </div>
        <div className="aspect-[3/4]">
          <Image src={Hives} alt="Hives" />
        </div>
      </div>

      

      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <h1 className="text-3xl">Ensuring the many vitamins, minerals, enzymes and antioxidants that honey contains are not lost before it reaches your kitchen. By experimenting with our own favoured organic herbs and spices we have added our infused range to our products. These are truly unique and proving very popular. Our hives are located in Norfolk, many of them on Ken Hill of Springwatch fame! They are free to gather the nectar from the coast of North Norfolk, the woodlands of Sandringham and Ken Hill and all the meadows and farmland in between.</h1>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
};
```

All I want is to get rid of the whitespace and the scrollbar it seems to create

Thank you

Comment: You need to create a reproducible example in codesandbox.io if you need better help

Answer (score 1):

```
className="**w-screen** h-screen text-black bg-white **max-w-screen**"
```

The w-screen container  should be changed to w-full.